# Google Map API vs MS virtual Earth API

Tags: google-maps, virtual-earth

I thought of using map in my blog. So which api will suit for me??
I am expecting that map should have more features. I dont know how to use it.. Sorry if my question is silly.
I need docs of both. Please let me know??

Comment: You can also take a look at http://www.openstreetmap.org

Comment: The question asked is unclear. What *exactly* you want to do with your map?

Answer (score 4):

Both mapping API's are well documented by the respective parties, just google it and you'll find what you need. The MS Api is a little more restrictive but then the MS maps have better support for bringing up nice looking pop-up boxes etc.

The only real considerations after working with both are design and whether you need https support or not because Google maps will give IE users on https a nasty security dialogue pop-up that won't go away unless you pay Google $10,000 (but being for your blog I wouldn't imagine your fussed about that)

Answer (score 2):

They are both pretty similar. I have used Google Maps API and it is very easy to get up and running and does everything I need. It also has street view which is a nice extra.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide us more details in order to get a better answer but I will give you my thoughts anyway:

I have used the virtual earth API in a project I did in 2007. By that time we decided to go for the MS version as it had a better documentation and would fit better with our technology set i.e. MS SQL, .NET etc .... and best of all: it was for free!

Google at that time was offering a nicer UI for maps and stuff but after a certain number of requests you would start getting charged....

If you are developing in .NET I would certainly go for Virtual Earth now as Microsoft has shipped the official virtual earth [sever side control](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtualearth/archive/2008/07/28/announcing-the-microsoft-virtual-earth-asp-net-server-control.aspx) ....

Some links:

http://dev.live.com/Virtualearth/sdk/

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think Virtual Earth is an inferior product compared to Google Maps with Street View.  I haven't looked at either API but my experience with using other web based APIs from Google and Microsoft is that Google exposes a lot more functionality.  The web is their bread and butter.  It's a defensive action from MS.  I love MS btw, so this isn't a hater ranting...

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure that MS Virtual Earth will require your users to download a viewer specific to actually see and interact with the map.  The Google API will work directly with the browser.  Really it comes down to what sort of functionality are you looking to include?  if you just want to display various places on a map then GoogleAPI will work fine for you, if you want to be able to do an exploded view of a location from 3 miles away and then zoom in on it like you would if you approached it in a fast moving plane then MS Earth.
[Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/) or [MS Earth Developers](http://www.microsoft.com/virtualearth/developers/)

Comment: MS Virtual Earth does not require a specific viewer application. See JS-based examples in The Virtual Earth Interactive SDK:
http://dev.live.com/virtualearth/sdk/

Comment: The woodlandtrust.org uses MS Virtual Earth. No need to download anything and I think it looks great and works well with this site. http://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/visiting-woods/map/norwich/52.63529968261719/1.2901400327682495/